# What should I use when trying to create a place to enter text when using FlowLayout?

Tags: java, swing, class, flowlayout

I have a school project which requires creating a GUI.  I am using flow-layout for the first time, and cannot figure out what I should use to create an area where I can enter text. None of the classes I used before work with flow-Layout.  It needs to be editable, be able to go to a string.  I just can't find a class that will work.

Here is my code as is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*; 
public class RedAliance extends JFrame
{
    JRadioButton number;
    JRadioButton name;
    JRadioButton city;
    JRadioButton state;
    FlowLayout experimentLayout = new FlowLayout();
    final String numberString = "By numer";
    final String nameString = "By Name";
    final String cityString = "By city";
    final String stateString = "By State";
    JButton search = new JButton("search");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
            try 
            {
                //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
            } 
            catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
            UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
            });
        } 

    public RedAliance(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void addComponentsToPane(final Container pane) {
        final JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(experimentLayout);
        experimentLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.TRAILING);
        JPanel controls = new JPanel();
        controls.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        number = new JRadioButton(numberString);
        number.setActionCommand(numberString);
        number.setSelected(true);

         name = new JRadioButton(nameString);
        name.setActionCommand(nameString);

        city  = new JRadioButton(cityString);
        city.setActionCommand(cityString);

        state = new JRadioButton(stateString);
        state.setActionCommand(stateString);

        final ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(number);
        group.add(name);
        group.add(city);
        group.add(state);

        controls.add(number);
        controls.add(name);
        controls.add(city);
        controls.add(state);
        controls.add(search);

        //Process the Apply component orientation button press
        search.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String command = group.getSelection().getActionCommand();
                String text= "";
                if (command.equals("By Name")) { byName(text);} 
                else if (command.equals("By Numer")) {
                }
                else if(command.equals("By State")){
                }
                else if(command.equals("By City")){
                }
                else {}
                //update the experiment layout
                p.validate();
                p.repaint();
            }

            });
        pane.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH); ;
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        RedAliance frame = new RedAliance("red"); //Create window
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void byName(String n)//returns the info on a team with this name
    {

    }
    public void byNumber(int n) //returns the info on a team with this number
    {

    }
    public void byCity(String c)//returns the info on all teams in this city
    {

    }
    public void byState(String s)//returns the info on all teams in this city
    {

    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "None of the classes I used before work with flow-Layout"? Did the size of your JTextField or other text component come out wrong?

Comment: I have literally never heard of JTextFields before. The "resource" I have been given for this is an 11 year old book.   How do you convert the entered text to a string?

Answer (score 0):

[flow layout javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) and sample code below should work.

> A flow layout arranges components in a directional flow, much like
>   lines of text in a paragraph. The flow direction is determined by the
>   container's componentOrientation property and may be one of two
>   values:

- ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT
- ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT

  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
      import java.awt.Container;
      import java.awt.FlowLayout;
      import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
      import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

  ```
  import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;
  import javax.swing.UIManager;
  import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

  public class test2 extends JFrame
  {
      JRadioButton number;
      JRadioButton name;
      JRadioButton city;
      JRadioButton state;
      JTextField textField;
      FlowLayout experimentLayout = new FlowLayout();
      final String numberString = "By numer";
      final String nameString = "By Name";
      final String cityString = "By city";
      final String stateString = "By State";
      JButton search = new JButton("search");

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
              try 
              {
                  //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
                  UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
              } 
              catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              }
              catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              } 
              catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              } 
              catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              }
              /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
              UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
              javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      createAndShowGUI();
                  }
              });
          } 

      public test2(String name) {
          super(name);
      }

      public void addComponentsToPane(final Container pane) {
          final JPanel p = new JPanel();
          p.setLayout(experimentLayout);
          experimentLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.TRAILING);
          JPanel controls = new JPanel();
          controls.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

          number = new JRadioButton(numberString);
          number.setActionCommand(numberString);
          number.setSelected(true);

           name = new JRadioButton(nameString);
          name.setActionCommand(nameString);

          city  = new JRadioButton(cityString);
          city.setActionCommand(cityString);

          state = new JRadioButton(stateString);
          state.setActionCommand(stateString);
          textField = new JTextField(10);
          final ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
          group.add(number);
          group.add(name);
          group.add(city);
          group.add(state);

          controls.add(number);
          controls.add(name);
          controls.add(city);
          controls.add(state);
          controls.add(textField);
          controls.add(search);


          //Process the Apply component orientation button press
          search.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
          {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {
                  String command = group.getSelection().getActionCommand();
                  String text= "";
                  if (command.equals("By Name")) { byName(text);} 
                  else if (command.equals("By Numer")) {
                  }
                  else if(command.equals("By State")){
                  }
                  else if(command.equals("By City")){
                  }
                  else {}
                  //update the experiment layout
                  p.validate();
                  p.repaint();
              }

              });
          pane.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
          pane.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH); ;
      }
      private static void createAndShowGUI() {
          test2 frame = new test2("red"); //Create window
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
      }
      public void byName(String n)//returns the info on a team with this name
      {

      }
      public void byNumber(int n) //returns the info on a team with this number
      {

      }
      public void byCity(String c)//returns the info on all teams in this city
      {

      }
      public void byState(String s)//returns the info on all teams in this city
      {

      }


  }
  ```